# Find ISO8895-1 encoded umlauts in UFT-8 file with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, utf-8, character-encoding

I have files that ought to be UTF-8 encoded. I believe `for reasons` some may contain ISO8859-1 encoded German umlauts. I thought I can start File Search `STRG+H` and search using a regular expression: `[\xe5\xf6\xfc\xc4\xd6\xdc\xdf\xa7]`. Interestingly it also returns umlauts that are correctly UTF-8 encoded - 2 bytes wide.
How can I find wrongly encoded umlauts?

I want to find one byte characters as defined in charset ISO8859-1 - higher than 127.
like `0xFC  0x00FC  #   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS`
as defined [here](ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-1.TXT)

This character exists in `UTF-8` and is two bytes wide: `C3 BC`

Comment: Add examples. What you can able to find and what you can't.